# Generate a django queryset based on dict keys

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I have a dict like:

```
{
    'key1' : val1,
    'key2' : val2
}
```

And I need a queryset like

```
Q(key1__icontains = val1) | Q(key2__icontains = val2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
reduce(operator.or_, Q(**{key + '__icontains': val}) for (key, val) in D.iteritems())
```

Comment: What do the double asterisks mean?

Comment: @Thr4wn: [Keyword expansion.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Answer (score 1):

There's a more pragmatic approach, as I need to generate various keys from one.

```
query = None
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if query is None:
        query = Q(**{key + "__icontains" : value})
    else:
        query |= Q(**{key + "__icontains" : value})
```