# convert list of dictionaries to Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
def db_data(request):
    grid_data = list(table_name.objects.all().values())
    return JsonResponse(grid_data, safe=False)
```

I am **hitting above endpoint** which gives list of dictionaries as response. Is there a way where I can convert this back to Queryset object at the receiver side so that I can perform ORM operations on this queryset object.

Comment: *"at the receiver side so that I can perform ORM operations"*, In your case what/who will be the *"receiver"*?

Comment: is it this which you are looking for @mahesh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350846/generate-a-django-queryset-based-on-dict-keys

Comment: **db_data** would be hosted on server1. `receiver would hit db_data and get the response in server2`